# Keras load model weights saved using scipy mat

Tags: python, keras, scipy

In Keras I trained a model and the saved its weights scipy.io savemat as:

```
sio.savemat('lstm_weights.mat',{'lstm_32':model.get_weights()})
```

Now I have loaded the weights in W and trying to use as:

```
model.set_weights(list(W['lstm_32'][0])
```

But this gives error: ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank

Can anyone help in how to load weights from mat file into model

Comment: Tell us about `model:get_weights()` (before the save), info like shape and dtype.  Then tell us about `W['lstm_32']`.  In other words, lets focus on the `savemat/loadmat` issue (without the `get_weights`/`set_weights` wrapping).

Comment: model.get_weights() is of len 32 and type list. W['lstm_32'] is of type array with shape (1,32)

Comment: `.mat` is a MATLAB compatible format, so it's returning a 2d array.  You need to correct the shape.